# Multiple output classification in Google AutoML Table

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, google-cloud-automl, automl

Is it possible to train a multiple output classification model using Google AutoML Table? If so, how can I predict a vector and not a scalar of multi-label classes with the AutoML Table? Concatenating the vector of output classes to get a single scalar as a workaround is not an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently this is not available. Please feel free to use "SEND FEEDBACK -> Product feedback" in the web page to send feedback for the feature request.